# best way display array order by key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

```
<?php
$array = array(
    "1" => 'Hi',
    "4" => 'are',
    "3" => 'How',
    "7" => 'my',
    "6" => 'you',
    "9" => 'brother',
);

forEach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo ':-';
    print_r($value);
    echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

the out put of this code is

```
1:-Hi
4:-are
3:-How
7:-my
6:-you
9:-brother
```

but i need to display this order by key. please tell me which is easiest way

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [ksort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php)

```
ksort($array);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo ':-';
    print_r($value);
    echo '<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The nice thing about PHP is that there's a function for everything. You can use the `ksort` function to sort the array by its keys: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ksort.php

Your new code would look like this:

```
<?php
$array = array(
"1" => 'Hi',
"4" => 'are',
"3" => 'How',
"7" => 'my',
"6" => 'you',
"9" => 'brother',
);

ksort($array);

forEach($array as $key => $value) {
echo $key;
echo ':-';
print_r($value);
echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```

Comment: asort is sort by value, not key. `a` means maintain index association

Answer (score 0):

use `ksort()`, this will arrange it by key order.

```
<?php
$array = array(
"1" => 'Hi',
"4" => 'are',
"3" => 'How',
"7" => 'my',
"6" => 'you',
"9" => 'brother',
);
ksort($array);

forEach($array as $key => $value) {
echo $key;
echo ':-';
print_r($value);
echo '<br/>';
}
?>
```